# Date Formatting On Kendo UI React Scheduler

Tags: reactjs, date, kendo-ui, format, scheduler

I tried to use KendoUI React Scheduler on my react js project but i stumbuled upon on how to format the start and end date to dd/mm/yyyy. I looked around KendoUI website and documentation, i couldn't find the way to do it.

The following below is my code:

[image]

This is how start and end date format look like, they are mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy.

[image]

I hope any of you guys can give me a hint or clue to get right.

Thanks